# Understanding Sum of product and complete sum of product

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I have a pair of problems, the first two of my homework, and I'm already unclear on how finding SOP and CSOP for them work. The first:

> E=xy(1+z)y'

It seems like this just reduces to 0, since 1+z is 1, and y * 1 is y, which is 0 due to y*y'. x*0 would result in 0. I don't know at what point I'm supposed to derive the SOP and CSOP from these.

The other problem I have is:

> E=(x+y')(x+y)

When I factor this out, I get:

> xx+xy+xy'+yy'
>
> =x+xy+xy'+0
>
> =x+(x*y)+xy'
>
> =x+xy'
>
> =x+(x*y')
>
> =x

Once again, I don't know where I should be deriving the SOP and CSOP. Please help?

Comment: Is this (Canonical) Sum Of Products described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form_%28Boolean_algebra%29)?

Comment: Unclear. My book defines SOP as a fundamental product or the sum of two or more fundamental products, none of which is contained in the other. CSOP is that, and each product contains all variables involved in an expression E.